# Как в js взять значение?

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

Есть js в нем много значений, мне нужно вытняуть одно, кроме того, как перевести в строку и обрезать, способов не нашел, может кто-то знает?
JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"Gncj2NRTbIHvWajRB5OX7PvvOO11I3V1","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"country_code":"RU","language_code":"ru","locale":"ru_RU","entry_data":{"LandingPage":[{"captcha":{"enabled":false,"key":""},"hsite_redirect_url":"","prefill_phone_number":"","gdpr_required":false,"tos_version":"row","sideload_url":null}]},"hostname":"www.instagram.com","is_whitelisted_crawl_bot":false,"deployment_stage":"c2","platform":"windows_nt_10","nonce":"yNxXV7ILDsnYYAf44WicmQ==","mid_pct":45.66293,"zero_data":{},"cache_schema_version":3,"server_checks":{},"knobx":{"4":false,"17":false,"20":true,"22":true,"23":true,"24":true,"25":true,"26":true},"to_cache":{"gatekeepers":{"4":true,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false,"8":false,"9":false,"10":false,"11":false,"12":false,"13":true,"14":true,"15":true,"16":true,"18":true,"19":false,"23":false,"24":false,"26":true,"27":false,"28":false,"29":true,"31":false,"32":true,"34":false,"35":false,"38":true,"40":true,"41":false,"43":true,"59":true,"61":false,"62":false,"63":false,"64":false,"65":false,"67":true,"68":false,"69":true,"71":false,"72":true,"73":false,"74":false,"75":true,"77":true,"78":true,"79":false,"81":false,"82":true,"84":false,"86":false,"88":true,"91":false,"95":true,"97":false,"99":false,"100":false,"101":false,"102":true,"103":false,"104":true,"105":true,"106":false,"107":false,"108":false},"qe":{"app_upsell":{"g":"","p":{}},"igl_app_upsell":{"g":"","p":{}},"notif":{"g":"","p":{}},"onetaplogin":{"g":"","p":{}},"multireg_iter":{"g":"control_11_30","p":{"has_back_removed":"false"}},"felix_clear_fb_cookie":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_creation_duration_limits":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_creation_fb_crossposting":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_creation_fb_crossposting_v2":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_creation_validation":{"g":"","p":{}},"mweb_topical_explore":{"g":"","p":{}},"post_options":{"g":"","p":{}},"iglscioi":{"g":"","p":{}},"sticker_tray":{"g":"","p":{}},"web_sentry":{"g":"","p":{}},"0":{"p":{"4":true,"7":true,"8":true,"9":false},"qex":true},"2":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"4":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"5":{"p":{"1":false},"qex":true},"6":{"p":{"1":true,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false,"9":false,"10":false},"qex":true},"10":{"p":{"2":false},"qex":true},"12":{"p":{"0":5},"qex":true},"13":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"16":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"17":{"p":{"1":true},"qex":true},"19":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"21":{"p":{"2":false},"qex":true},"22":{"p":{"1":false,"2":8.0,"3":0.85,"4":0.95,"10":0.0,"11":15,"12":3,"13":false},"qex":true},"23":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"25":{"p":{},"qex":true},"26":{"p":{"0":""},"qex":true},"28":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"29":{"p":{},"qex":true},"30":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"31":{"p":{},"qex":true},"33":{"p":{},"qex":true},"34":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"35":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"36":{"p":{"0":true,"1":true,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false},"qex":true},"37":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"39":{"p":{"0":false,"6":false,"7":false,"8":false,"14":false},"qex":true},"41":{"p":{"3":true},"qex":true},"42":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"43":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false,"2":false},"qex":true},"44":{"p":{"1":"inside_media","2":0.2},"qex":true},"45":{"p":{"12":false,"13":false,"17":0,"18":false,"19":2,"22":false,"23":"control","24":false,"25":"control","26":"control","32":false,"33":false},"qex":true},"46":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"47":{"p":{"0":true,"1":true,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false,"6":false,"8":false,"9":false,"10":false,"11":false},"qex":true},"49":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"50":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"53":{"p":{"0":5},"qex":true},"54":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"55":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"56":{"p":{"1":true,"2":true},"qex":true},"58":{"p":{"0":0.0,"1":false},"qex":true},"59":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"62":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"64":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"65":{"p":{},"qex":true},"66":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"67":{"p":{"0":true,"1":true,"2":true,"3":true,"4":false,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false},"qex":true},"68":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"69":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"70":{"p":{"1":"Instagram\u306f\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u3067\u3088\u308a\u5feb\u9069\u306b\u3054\u5229\u7528\u306b\u306a\u308c\u307e\u3059","2":"\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u306b\u306f\u3088\u308a\u591a\u304f\u306e\u30ab\u30e1\u30e9\u30a8\u30d5\u30a7\u30af\u30c8\u3084\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3\u30d7\u304c\u3042\u308a\u307e\u3059\u3002\u30e1\u30c3\u30bb\u30fc\u30b8\u3092\u9001\u4fe1\u3059\u308b\u65b9\u6cd5\u3082\u3088\u308a\u591a\u304f\u3042\u308a\u307e\u3059\u3002","3":"\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u3092\u5229\u7528"},"qex":true},"71":{"p":{"1":"^/explore/.*|^/accounts/activity/$"},"qex":true},"72":{"p":{"0":false,"1":true,"2":true,"3":false,"4":false},"qex":true},"73":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"74":{"p":{"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false,"8":false,"9":false,"10":false},"qex":true},"75":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"76":{"p":{"0":true,"1":false},"qex":true},"77":{"p":{"0":true,"1":false},"qex":true},"78":{"p":{"0":true,"1":false},"qex":true},"80":{"p":{"3":false},"qex":true},"81":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"84":{"p":{"0":true,"1":true,"2":true,"3":false,"4":true,"5":true,"6":false,"8":false},"qex":true},"85":{"p":{"0":false,"1":"Pictures and Videos"},"qex":true},"87":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"89":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"91":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"92":{"p":{"0":36},"qex":true},"93":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"95":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"96":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"97":{"p":{},"qex":true},"98":{"p":{"1":false},"qex":true},"99":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"100":{"p":{},"qex":true},"101":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"102":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"103":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"104":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"105":{"p":{"0":"control"},"qex":true},"106":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"107":{"p":{},"qex":true},"108":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"109":{"p":{},"qex":true},"110":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true}},"probably_has_app":false,"cb":false},"device_id":"AEB84A40-C6F6-4FA6-B1F5-D2B64F8C51B0","encryption":{"key_id":"155","public_key":"4fd28ee2f38b02707cf2478111e82ed6c3d9fb4e181768d4bc15b6aae1474a45"},"rollout_hash":"3aed6acc7f7a","bundle_variant":"es6","is_canary":false};
</script>
```

Вытянуть нужно crf_token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        a = {"config":{"csrf_token":"Gncj2NRTbIHvWajRB5OX7PvvOO11I3V1","viewer":null,"viewerId":null}}
        console.log( a.config.csrf_token )
        console.log( a.config['csrf_token'] )
        console.log( a['config']['csrf_token'] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Здраствуйте, обратится к полю объекта в JavaScript возможно следующим образом:

```js
window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"Gncj2NRTbIHvWajRB5OX7PvvOO11I3V1","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"country_code":"RU","language_code":"ru","locale":"ru_RU","entry_data":{"LandingPage":[{"captcha":{"enabled":false,"key":""},"hsite_redirect_url":"","prefill_phone_number":"","gdpr_required":false,"tos_version":"row","sideload_url":null}]},"hostname":"www.instagram.com","is_whitelisted_crawl_bot":false,"deployment_stage":"c2","platform":"windows_nt_10","nonce":"yNxXV7ILDsnYYAf44WicmQ==","mid_pct":45.66293,"zero_data":{},"cache_schema_version":3,"server_checks":{},"knobx":{"4":false,"17":false,"20":true,"22":true,"23":true,"24":true,"25":true,"26":true},"to_cache":{"gatekeepers":{"4":true,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false,"8":false,"9":false,"10":false,"11":false,"12":false,"13":true,"14":true,"15":true,"16":true,"18":true,"19":false,"23":false,"24":false,"26":true,"27":false,"28":false,"29":true,"31":false,"32":true,"34":false,"35":false,"38":true,"40":true,"41":false,"43":true,"59":true,"61":false,"62":false,"63":false,"64":false,"65":false,"67":true,"68":false,"69":true,"71":false,"72":true,"73":false,"74":false,"75":true,"77":true,"78":true,"79":false,"81":false,"82":true,"84":false,"86":false,"88":true,"91":false,"95":true,"97":false,"99":false,"100":false,"101":false,"102":true,"103":false,"104":true,"105":true,"106":false,"107":false,"108":false},"qe":{"app_upsell":{"g":"","p":{}},"igl_app_upsell":{"g":"","p":{}},"notif":{"g":"","p":{}},"onetaplogin":{"g":"","p":{}},"multireg_iter":{"g":"control_11_30","p":{"has_back_removed":"false"}},"felix_clear_fb_cookie":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_creation_duration_limits":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_creation_fb_crossposting":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_creation_fb_crossposting_v2":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_creation_validation":{"g":"","p":{}},"mweb_topical_explore":{"g":"","p":{}},"post_options":{"g":"","p":{}},"iglscioi":{"g":"","p":{}},"sticker_tray":{"g":"","p":{}},"web_sentry":{"g":"","p":{}},"0":{"p":{"4":true,"7":true,"8":true,"9":false},"qex":true},"2":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"4":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"5":{"p":{"1":false},"qex":true},"6":{"p":{"1":true,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false,"9":false,"10":false},"qex":true},"10":{"p":{"2":false},"qex":true},"12":{"p":{"0":5},"qex":true},"13":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"16":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"17":{"p":{"1":true},"qex":true},"19":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"21":{"p":{"2":false},"qex":true},"22":{"p":{"1":false,"2":8.0,"3":0.85,"4":0.95,"10":0.0,"11":15,"12":3,"13":false},"qex":true},"23":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"25":{"p":{},"qex":true},"26":{"p":{"0":""},"qex":true},"28":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"29":{"p":{},"qex":true},"30":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"31":{"p":{},"qex":true},"33":{"p":{},"qex":true},"34":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"35":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"36":{"p":{"0":true,"1":true,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false},"qex":true},"37":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"39":{"p":{"0":false,"6":false,"7":false,"8":false,"14":false},"qex":true},"41":{"p":{"3":true},"qex":true},"42":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"43":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false,"2":false},"qex":true},"44":{"p":{"1":"inside_media","2":0.2},"qex":true},"45":{"p":{"12":false,"13":false,"17":0,"18":false,"19":2,"22":false,"23":"control","24":false,"25":"control","26":"control","32":false,"33":false},"qex":true},"46":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"47":{"p":{"0":true,"1":true,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false,"6":false,"8":false,"9":false,"10":false,"11":false},"qex":true},"49":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"50":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"53":{"p":{"0":5},"qex":true},"54":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"55":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"56":{"p":{"1":true,"2":true},"qex":true},"58":{"p":{"0":0.0,"1":false},"qex":true},"59":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"62":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"64":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"65":{"p":{},"qex":true},"66":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"67":{"p":{"0":true,"1":true,"2":true,"3":true,"4":false,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false},"qex":true},"68":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"69":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"70":{"p":{"1":"Instagram\u306f\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u3067\u3088\u308a\u5feb\u9069\u306b\u3054\u5229\u7528\u306b\u306a\u308c\u307e\u3059","2":"\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u306b\u306f\u3088\u308a\u591a\u304f\u306e\u30ab\u30e1\u30e9\u30a8\u30d5\u30a7\u30af\u30c8\u3084\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3\u30d7\u304c\u3042\u308a\u307e\u3059\u3002\u30e1\u30c3\u30bb\u30fc\u30b8\u3092\u9001\u4fe1\u3059\u308b\u65b9\u6cd5\u3082\u3088\u308a\u591a\u304f\u3042\u308a\u307e\u3059\u3002","3":"\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u3092\u5229\u7528"},"qex":true},"71":{"p":{"1":"^/explore/.*|^/accounts/activity/$"},"qex":true},"72":{"p":{"0":false,"1":true,"2":true,"3":false,"4":false},"qex":true},"73":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"74":{"p":{"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false,"5":false,"6":false,"7":false,"8":false,"9":false,"10":false},"qex":true},"75":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"76":{"p":{"0":true,"1":false},"qex":true},"77":{"p":{"0":true,"1":false},"qex":true},"78":{"p":{"0":true,"1":false},"qex":true},"80":{"p":{"3":false},"qex":true},"81":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"84":{"p":{"0":true,"1":true,"2":true,"3":false,"4":true,"5":true,"6":false,"8":false},"qex":true},"85":{"p":{"0":false,"1":"Pictures and Videos"},"qex":true},"87":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"89":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"91":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"92":{"p":{"0":36},"qex":true},"93":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"95":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"96":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"97":{"p":{},"qex":true},"98":{"p":{"1":false},"qex":true},"99":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true},"100":{"p":{},"qex":true},"101":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"102":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"103":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"104":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"105":{"p":{"0":"control"},"qex":true},"106":{"p":{"0":true},"qex":true},"107":{"p":{},"qex":true},"108":{"p":{"0":false,"1":false},"qex":true},"109":{"p":{},"qex":true},"110":{"p":{"0":false},"qex":true}},"probably_has_app":false,"cb":false},"device_id":"AEB84A40-C6F6-4FA6-B1F5-D2B64F8C51B0","encryption":{"key_id":"155","public_key":"4fd28ee2f38b02707cf2478111e82ed6c3d9fb4e181768d4bc15b6aae1474a45"},"rollout_hash":"3aed6acc7f7a","bundle_variant":"es6","is_canary":false};

_sharedData.config.csrf_token //получить данные поля
console.log(_sharedData.config.csrf_token) //вывести данные с поля в консоль
```

Преобразовать объект в строку возможно через `JSON`:

```js
let object = { name: 'Ivan' }

let objectString = JSON.stringify(object)

console.log(objectString) // "{ "name": "Ivan" }"
```